# SQL Server numerical reference column decode

Tags: sql, sql-server, ascii, non-ascii-characters, extended-ascii

Is there a way to decode all the characters with numerical reference in SQL (ex. , 'solu&#231 ;&#227 ;o' -> solução , "&#26696 ; -> 案" )  from a column ?

The space before ";" is not the issue , just added so it would not be embedded .

What i found so far :

- use htmldecode C# (not an option)
- use replace for every value (only possible if someone took the time to actually add every char )

Comment: what do you mean by " decode all the characters with numerical reference in SQL"   sample input output please

Comment: Hi @nikhilsugandh from " &#12371;&#12435;&#12395;&#12385;&#12399; , this is a  &#26679;&#21697; &#169; " to こんにちは , this is a 样品 ®

Comment: It looks like HTML or XML so has nothing to do with ASCII or "Extended" ASCII. Both systems use the Unicode character set, including for numeric character entity references. You should find out which it is: HTML or XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the field is for—or its data is and always will be compatible with—XML, convert it to the XML type and then take the text value:

```
SELECT N'&#128690;', CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), CONVERT(XML, N'&#128690;'));
```

Otherwise, one way is to create a [SQL CLR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/clr-user-defined-functions) function to use .NET's HTML libraries. (If you have something against C#, there are other .NET languages.)

And, depending on your version of SQL Server and operating system, there are [R libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/tutorials/rtsql-using-r-functions-with-sql-server-data?view=sql-server-2017) and [Python libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/tutorials/run-python-using-t-sql?view=sql-server-2017) that can be made accessible to T-SQL.